# Positive universal sum of fourth powers with coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory

[Sums of four fourth powers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74921/sums-of-four-fourth-powers)
reminded me of this: among many similar items, I have a  conjecture that this 16-variable polynomial

$$  \begin{array}{rrc} & w_1^4 + w_2^4 + w_3^4 + w_4^4 & + \\\ 5 & (x_1^4 + x_2^4 + x_3^4 + x_4^4) & + \\\  25 & (y_1^4 + y_2^4 + y_3^4 + y_4^4)& + \\\ 125 & (z_1^4 + z_2^4 + z_3^4 + z_4^4) &  \end{array} $$
integrally represents all positive integers. Given that they settled $g(4)$ it would seem the machinery to prove this is available. I found some 25 million of these expressions, sum of from 7 to about 23 biquadrates with coefficients that appear to represent all positive integers. The minimum (7 with coefficients) was found by L.E. Dickson. This example surprised me. One can at least prove that some positive integer $n$ is represented if and only if $5n$ is represented.

Edit: well, I cannot seem to find paper records of this. Probably around here somewhere. The part about $n$ and $5n$ comes from the observation that any fourth power is either $1 \pmod 5$ or $ 0 \pmod {625}.$

Comment: With a highly symmetric (and regular) form of your quartic, I wonder whether there exists a reduction to quadratics. Something like (Lucas's?) $$ 6\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^2\biggr)^2 = \sum_{1\le i<j\le 4}((x_i+x_j)^4+(x_i-x_j)^4). $$